# CSS class for two elements doesn't respond correctly

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I am currently using one CSS class for two elements but when I use the css code to change properties nothing happens. I know it's a beginner mistake but I really can't see my error. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
  <div class="footer-main">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="field-third">
            <div class="f-holder">
                <h3>Got a Query?</h3><br>
                <a href="#" class="button white">Send</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-third">
            <img src="/public/images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="field-third">
            <div class="f-holder">
                <h3>Get in touch!</h3>
                <div><span class="highlight">T:</span> 222222222222222</div>
                <div><span class="highlight">Shop:</span> 22222222222222</div>
                <div><span class="highlight">E:</span> reception@something.com</div><br>
                <br>
                <div><span class="highlight">Mon to Fri:</span> 9am to 6pm</div>
                <div><span class="highlight">Sat to Sun:</span> 9am to 4pm</div>
                <a href="#" class="button white">Book Online</a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the **class = "field-third"**, which changes only the second element. Here is my CSS code as well for the given class:

```
    .f-holder {
float:right;
background-color: rgba(4, 32, 44, 0.9);
padding: 50px 40px;
width: 355px;
hight:437px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the correct class name?

Comment: I notice you mistyped height in your css, could that be the problem?

Comment: Yep,saw it just now...I've mistyped hegiht. The other thing is that I have to center one element to the left and the other to the right in the same CSS class code. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance again..

Answer (score 0):

You should clear after floating of elements. There are three variants:

1.The first variant is to use clearfix by adding clearfix class to `<div class="field-third">` - `<div class="field-third clearfix">`. After that add clearfix style:

```
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
```

2.The second variant is to set a height to field-third.

3.The third variant is by adding width and overflow: hidden; to field-third.

```
.field-third {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

But the best variant is the first one.